# Tcsh command history

Tags: shell, history, tcsh

I use tcsh and have the following in my .cshrc file. But the .history file is not updated as and when I execute a command. Is there anyway so that .history file is updated every time I execute a command ?

```
set history=500
set savehist=1
set histfile = ~/.history
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually update the file with `history -S`

In tcsh, you can make an alias that runs when each command is actually executed:

```
alias precmd 'history -S'
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the history preserved between multiple simultaneous sessions, you also want to merge the histories:

```
alias precmd 'history -S; history -M'
```

Also - you don't want `savehist` set to `1` - that will only save one line of history.  Instead use:

```
set savehist (500 merge)
```

to save 500 lines of history